# MySQL Workbench Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have been fiddeling with MySQL Workbench as a learning project and tried to create a table with foreign keys.
The Keys reference other tables in my database.
The ID's which are beeing referenced are all of the same type "INT(11)".
All the ID's are primary Keys and are not null.

Yet I still cant forward Engineer my Database, and the following error is beeing thrown: "ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `testcrm`.`role_user` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")"

---

```
    -- Table `testcrm`.`role_user`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testcrm`.`role_user` (
      `role_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `user_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`, `user_id`),
      INDEX `user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `role_user_role_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`)
        REFERENCES `testcrm`.`roles` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
      CONSTRAINT `role_user_user_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
        REFERENCES `testcrm`.`users` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Edit: Those are my Users and Roles Tables:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testcrm`.`roles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testcrm`.`roles` (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(191) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testcrm`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testcrm`.`users` (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
`email_verified_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
`remember_token` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX `users_email_unique` (`email` ASC),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: _All the ID's are primary Keys and are nullable_ ???

Comment: Sorry I ment not null.
In my role_user table the primary keys are role_id and user_id which then reference the field id in both my roles and users table. The ID's in those tables are also primary keys

Comment: where is the `CREATE TABLE` of `roles`, `users`?

Comment: I edited my question to add both of these

Comment: your 3 create statements are executed correctly on my MySQL 5.7 : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05ca4e